# Cannot install/update NUGET Package Manager in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, path, environment-variables, nuget-package

When I attempt to update the NuGet Package Manager in VS2012 I get a "The system cannot find the path specified" error.  I tried uninstalling the package so I could do a fresh install from scratch, but I get the same error.

I have searched here, and the internet generally, for the exact text of the error message as well as more general searches related to problems with paths in VS2012, etc.

I have discovered that none of the environment variables/paths under Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Environment Security are valid and I suspect this is the root of my problem, but I cannot find a reference for how these variables should be configured.

The list includes:  %APPDATA%, %ALLUSERSPROFILE%, %VSAPPDATA%, %VSCOMMONAPPDATA%, and %VSMYDOCUMENTS%

Can anyone give me guidance on how to properly configure these, and/or any other ideas that might help me get the NuGet Package Manager reinstalled on my machine?

JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stumbled across the solution to this problem, while fixing another issue.

Let's start with a Microsoft KB article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327763

It turns out that there are several registry entries that need to be checked to make sure they all make sense for your environment.  In my case several of the entries erroneously pointed at a network location instead of "My Documents," so installations and updates that depended on these entries, but checked them for validity, caused an error.  One such update was the NuGet Package Manager, referenced in my question.

I fixed the registry entries referenced in the KB article and NuGet (as well as several other things) work perfectly now.

Hope this helps someone besides me!